# Trouble Using an If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to create a table that will generate numbers to round to a specified place value.  The table (in HTML code) is shown below.

```
        <table border = "1">

            <col width = "25">
            <col width = "150">
            <col width = "100">
            <col width = "100">
            <col width = "50">

            <tr><td>  </td><td>Place Vaue</td><td>Value</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>a.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion1"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue1"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>b.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion2"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue2"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>c.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion3"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue3"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>d.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion4"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue4"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>d.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion5"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue5"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>e.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion6"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue6"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>f.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion7"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue7"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>g.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion8"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue8"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>h.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion9"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue9"></span></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>i.</td><td><span id = "roundingQuestion10"></span></td><td><span id = "placeValue10"></span></td><td></td></tr>

        </table>        

        <br />
        <br />

        <button onclick="createRoundingQuestions()">Create Questions</button>
```

The javascript file that I am using to do this is:

```
var placeValueName = ["Thousandth", "Hundredth", "Tenth", "Ones", "tens", "Hundreds", "Thousands", "Ten Thousands", "Hundred Thousands"];

function getRndInteger(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}

function createRoundingQuestions(){
    var j;
    var x;
    var numberDecimals;
    var lowValue;
    var highValue;

    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
        x = getRndInteger(0, placeValueName.length, 0);

        document.getElementById("roundingQuestion"+j).innerHTML = placeValueName[x]; 
        document.getElementById("number"+j).innerHTML = x;

        if (x >= 5){
            lowValue = Math.pow(10, x - 3);
            highValue = Math.pow(10, x - 2);
            numberDecimals = getRndInteger(0, 6);
        } else if (x >= 3) && (x < 5){
            lowValue = 1;
            highValue = 1000;
            numberDecimals = getRndInteger(1, 3);
        } else {
            lowValue = 1;
            highValue = 1000;
            numberDecimals = getRndInteger(2, 6);
        }

        document.getElementById("placeValue"+j).innerHTML = (Math.random() * (highValue - lowValue) ) + lowValue).tofixed(numberDecimals);
    }
}
```

The first part of the javascript file works.  It will add the place value (thousands, hundreds, tens, etc.) to each row of the table.  However, when I include the If Statement to detemine the number and the proper number of decimal places, the output is a blank table that will not populate.  I would appreciate if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong and suggest how to fix it.

Comment: The entire condition of an if statement must be within parentheses. (see your `else if` condition.

Comment: What @MikeMcCaughan said, you need to change `} else if (x >= 3) && (x < 5){` to `} else if ((x >= 3) && (x < 5)){`

Comment: Opening your browser's console would probably have pointed you to the right place right away...

Comment: can you share a working jsfiddle or somthing?

Answer (score 0):

here it is, you got a lot of missing code / typos...

```js
var placeValueName = ["Thousandth", "Hundredth", "Tenth", "Ones", "tens", "Hundreds", "Thousands", "Ten Thousands", "Hundred Thousands"];

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function createRoundingQuestions() {
  var j;
  var x;
  var numberDecimals;
  var lowValue;
  var highValue;

  for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    x = getRndInteger(0, placeValueName.length, 0);

    document.getElementById("roundingQuestion" + j).innerHTML = placeValueName[x];
    document.getElementById("number" + j).innerHTML = x;

    if (x >= 5) {
      lowValue = Math.pow(10, x - 3);
      highValue = Math.pow(10, x - 2);
      numberDecimals = getRndInteger(0, 6);
    } else if ((x >= 3) && (x < 5)){
      lowValue = 1;
      highValue = 1000;
      numberDecimals = getRndInteger(1, 3);
    } else {
      lowValue = 1;
      highValue = 1000;
      numberDecimals = getRndInteger(2, 6);
    }

    document.getElementById("placeValue" + j).innerHTML = (Math.random() * (highValue - lowValue)) + (lowValue).toFixed(numberDecimals);
}
}
```

```html
<table border="1">

  <col width="25">
  <col width="150">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="50">

  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Place Vaue</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number1"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion2"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue2"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number2"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion3"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue3"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number3"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion4"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue4"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number4"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion5"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue5"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number5"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion6"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue6"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number6"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion7"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue7"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number7"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion8"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue8"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number8"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>h.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion9"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue9"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number9"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>i.</td>
    <td><span id="roundingQuestion10"></span></td>
    <td><span id="placeValue10"></span></td>
    <td><span id="number10"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<br />
<br />

<button onclick="createRoundingQuestions()">Create Questions</button>
```